Should we allow minor edits for 0 points as Wikipedia does?
If the site allowed minor edits--the correction of up to three language errors--by folks who have reached a certain point level or number of edits, we might see many posts get cleaned up very quickly and readability improved significantly.
Speed-bump grammar mistakes--verb tense, missing definite and indefinite articles, a missing comma, typos, egregious spelling mistakes, capitalization errors, etc.--would start to disappear silently. The reward of +2 could go to folks who do work above the threshold of the minor edit.
Right now it seems that correcting the one or two language mistakes that sometimes pop up in a piece--no matter how glaring--amounts to a "trivial" edit.  Why not set clear standards for minor edits and then trust certain users to fix trivial mistakes quickly? 

This is more of a feature request, which would have to be handled and implemented by SE employees in case they think your suggested feature makes sense. I‘ve therefore tagged your question accordingly using the [tag:feature-request] tag.

@e-sushi Right, I should have realized that.

Minor edits have been discussed a lot on the main meta. “Minor edit” check box, make them non-bumping, stop rejecting minor edits (but sub-6-character edits are still blocked), … I'm pretty sure I've seen “allow minor edits with no reputation” but all I can find are variants 1 2 3

@Gilles Thank you. I'll go there and say something. Blocking the sub-6-character edits allows misunderstandings to flourish. There is another aspect to this question which should be considered:  some people do not take kindly to having their work corrected. Edits with 0 points that are invisible will make many people more comfortable with coming onto this site and making contributions in English, which may not be their native language.
